# SQL Server Monitoring

Tags: sql-server, performance, monitoring, snmp

I am looking for some open source software which I can use to monitor Microsoft SQL server 2005 & 2008.

The features that I would like include:

- Graphing
- Recording of CPU usage
- Recording of Disk I/O stats
- Be able to setup notifications when a counter passes a threshold

I would also if possible like to incorporate some SQL server specific metrics like buffer cache hits, number of sessions etc...

Can anyone make any recomendations as to what you use in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something cheap and quick (which it doesn't sound like, but just in case), try [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/).

If you'd like an actual NICE graphing solution, I'd recommend [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) (they have a free and a commercial version) or [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), which is free.

Both of these have great interfaces, pretty graphs, and send alerts based on thresholds.

Comment: Zenoss looks like a good solution and combined with the SQL Server Zen packs it should give me what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We use [SCOM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/operationsmanager/en/us/default.aspx) but that's probably more than you need, although it is the ultimate (we use it to monitor more than 100,000 servers).  [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is a popular bit of monitoring software that is open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) and get SQL Server specific information with [Performance Counters](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1265).